# solr stops right after it starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

We are trying to deploy our rails app , however when we run the command :

`bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`

solr starts successfully but it terminates after 10 seconds with this error:

`ERROR -- : Couldn't cleanly terminate all actors in 10 seconds!`

Because of this problem we are unable to reindexing because solr is not running.

We have searched and we didn't find the solution , thank you

Comment: That's a ruby error message - what's the actual Solr message from its log? Does it start if you start it outside of the rake script?

Comment: @MatsLindh when I run the command and run this command `ps aux | grep solr` I get the solr pid but after ten seconds I get the error and the process gets killed , I'm not sure why

Comment: That sounds like a ruby / rake issue - maybe Solr takes more than ten seconds to start up? Check how far it gets in the Solr log if available, or start Solr outside of the rake script.

Comment: @MatsLindh as I said the process gets killed right after the error , there is no solr log (or at least I don't know where to find it) it is not in the log folder and not in the solr folder. how can I start it without rake ?